# lxml parsing google search results

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to parse the links from google search results and end up with weird output.

```
import mechanize, re, lxml.html
from lxml.html import parse
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1)     Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')] 
br.set_handle_robots(False)
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=test&gl=US'

response = br.open(url)
html = response.read().lower()

doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)

for t in doc.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a"):
    print t.get('href')
```

which results in the following output:
[image: Screenshot]

Any help would be great,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to achieve here, because you're getting exactly what you're asking for there.

```
<h3 class="r">
  <a href="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=web&amp;cd=1&amp;cad=rja&amp;ved=0CDUQFjAA&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2F&amp;ei=bdMEUYXiBefS2AXL5oGoBQ&amp;usg=AFQjCNH21KLjC0CBkjon2DwD_CZ0HApLMw&amp;sig2=KeRdw0_WAGc2Zrz1jI49wQ&amp;bvm=bv.41524429,d.b2I" 
  class="l" 
  onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNH21KLjC0CBkjon2DwD_CZ0HApLMw','KeRdw0_WAGc2Zrz1jI49wQ','0CDUQFjAA','','',event)">
    <em>Test</em>.com
  </a>
</h3>
```

You're getting the `href` attribute of the inner `a` tag, which comes out to:

```
"/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=web&amp;cd=1&amp;cad=rja&amp;ved=0CDUQFjAA&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2F&amp;ei=bdMEUYXiBefS2AXL5oGoBQ&amp;usg=AFQjCNH21KLjC0CBkjon2DwD_CZ0HApLMw&amp;sig2=KeRdw0_WAGc2Zrz1jI49wQ&amp;bvm=bv.41524429,d.b2I"
```

But more likely you're looking for the link text and the link link. The URL that you'll be sent to, without the Google special url stuff is in the `cite` element, and the link text is in the `a` element you've already found.

Comment: Oh, you are right - it was late ;). Yes I am looking for the link and text. But when I change my code to this: doc.xpath("//div[@class='f kv']/cite"), I get empty output. Am I doing something wrong

Comment: Try a period between `f` and `kv`, maybe

Comment: /cite does not return the exact URL, if it is too long it returns "..." inside the URL.